# SurfaceView is black after returning from other activity

Tags: android

I have bulit a TicTacToe game for Android and for starting a new game I call `startActvityForResult()` to let the user choose some options in the new Actvity. Then I call `setResult()` and `finish()` to get back to my gameActivity containing the SurfaceView in a LinearLayout.

But here comes the Problem: The whole SurfaceView is just a black area until I tap somewhere, then it acts as it should: the `onTouchEvent()` method is called and the game becomes visible.

Any ideas how I can get rid of that black screen? 
I already tried setting the LinearLayout and the SurfaceView visible/invisible during onResume()/onPause. And `invalidate()`or `postInvalidate()`don't work either.

I found out it seems that it is displayed correctly, if the surface is drawn twice, so I call `postInvalidate()`inside of `draw()`via a boolean flag.

Answer (score 0):

This is difficult to answer without any code or more detailed information, but you should start/stop rendering to your surface view in the `onPause()`/`onResume()`, or in the `onSurfaceDestroyed()`/`onSurfaceCreated()` methods. So basically, you must properly handle the surface view in the activity lifecycle.

[This](https://source.android.com/devices/graphics/architecture.html#activity) is quite specifically dealing with this topic (activity lifecycle + surface view).

As a quick fix, you could just try calling `onTouchEvent()` manually in `onResume` or `onSurfaceCreated()`.

Comment: I just didn't know which code parts would be the most helping ones.